# Getting Unhandled Runtime Error, Error: "undefined" is not valid JSON in when importing Client component to server component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have trying to implement a simple counter component that will increase the count of the state variable when a button is clicked, so i made a separate file Couter.tsx and placed into the component folder in the root of the next project. Here is the code for the Counter.tsx file -

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when i import this component into the main page.tsx file, I get this strange error -

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: "undefined" is not valid JSON

Call Stack
React
updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (16088:0)
updateSuspenseComponent
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15788:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (17103:0)
beginWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25615:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24465:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24181:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (24146:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23250:0)
workLoop
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\index.js (10:3921)
flushWork
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\index.js (10:3629)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\index.js (10:1811)
```

What did I do wrong here? I have been trying to find a solution for a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no error in my code, it turns out that my internet connection was not working at that time. The code runs find on other computers which have a proper network connection. I just wasted 1 day fixing the non existent problem in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your component code works just fine, here is a [Stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pqhqaw?file=pages/index.tsx) of your app.

Note that imports can use aliases, the example above uses a relative import path.

Comment: Yes, there was a error in my internet connection.